# Ibid source citing source

Tags: citation, mla

I have a source (source A) citing source B and source C in the next citation number. I want to cite both B and C. So obviously, I should cite A, B, and C. how should I do this?

> 1. Source B
>      (citing Source A pp. 334)
> 2. Source C
>      (citing Source A pp. 345)

OR

> 1. Source B
>      (citing Source A pp. 334)
> 2. Source C
>      (citing Ibid. at pp. 345)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about citation style, which belongs on writers.se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sup>1</sup> Dewey 1983, 173 (citing Louie 1894, 334)
>   <sup>2</sup> Huey 2012, 227 (citing *ibid*., 345)

This is impossible, because it leaves it unclear whether *ibid* refers to Louie 1894 or Dewey 1983. You need:

> <sup>2</sup> Huey 2012, 227 (citing Louie 1894, 345)

But you are better served by omitting *ibid* and *op cit* and the like altogether. The purpose of documentation is to make it possible for the reader to locate your sources. *Your* purpose should be to make that as easy as possible. Do them the courtesy of telling them what they need at the point where you tell them you're going to tell them (in footnote 2, here); don’t make them go look it up somewhere else (in footnote 1, here).